# How to access component function inside getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs

How do I call a component function inside static getDerivedStateFromProps?

This is my code

```
class Box extends Component {

  updateVariables() {
    this.statColorClass = "no-change";
    if(this.props.dir === "up") {
      this.statColorClass = "up";
      this.dirIcon = <GoArrowUp />;
    } else if (this.props.dir === "down") {
      this.statColorClass = "down";
      this.dirIcon = <GoArrowDown />;
    }
  }
  static getDerivedStateFromProps() {
    this.updateVariables(); // not working
  }
 render() {}
}
```

The line `this.updateVariables();` is not working. How do I call `updateVariables()` ?

Comment: Please, list the whole component. It's unclear where these properties are used. Most likely you have XY problem.

Comment: did you bind `updateVariables` ?

Comment: @estus the code above is the full component, the props and variables are used inside the render(), this looks a prob of this not accessible inside static func

Comment: @ThilinaSampath No, is that needed in this scenario?

Comment: I think please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is intended to update component state from received props. It was deliberately designed to not allow access to component instance.

`statColorClass`, etc. properties represent component state, but they aren't parts of `state`, this is rarely needed in React stateful components. A proper solution would be to refactor component to use `state`:

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    state = {...state, statColorClass: "no-change" };

    if (props.dir === "up") {
      state.statColorClass = "up";
      state.dirIcon = <GoArrowUp />;
    } else if (props.dir === "down") {
      state.statColorClass = "down";
      state.dirIcon = <GoArrowDown />;
    }

    return state;
  }
```

Comment: getting error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: Fixed. It's `props`, not `this.props`.

Answer (score 5):

`this` cannot be accessed inside static functions, that is by design. Still if you want to get `this` inside getDerivedStateFromProps, you could use the below code, but you should never use like this.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    currentInstance: this
  }
}
```

Now inside your `getDerivedStateFromProps()` access `currentInstance` which is same as `this`

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
   state.currentInstance.updateVariables();
}
```

Comment: as you mentioned you should not use like this then why you have posted @kiranvj . does it create any critical error  ?  I am new bee to react so could you please explain a bit more on that

Comment: @SakthiSureshAnand getDerivedStateFromProps is a static function. So `this` is not accessible inside it. Do you have any use case where you need to use `this` ? Please see accepted answer for the actual intention of `getDerivedStateFromProps`. My answer is just a work around not the actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

This method doesn’t have access to the component instance. If you want to reuse functionality then you could create pure components outside the class. The whole point of this function is to convert props to new state, which is what the static function should return. It is not intended to cause side effects. Not sure why you are using instance vars to handle state.

Comment: I am removing `componentWillReceiveProps` in react 16.3 with `getDerivedStateFromProps`. So I used the same code which was in `componentWillReceiveProps` Maybe I should change my logic.

Comment: Yeah. Basically you take props as a param to the static function and then return an object that represents the state you want. In your case you want to change the icon and color. Store them in the state and return them from getDerivedStateFromProps. Long name but describes exactly what it does.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using component states since I am using redux store. If no other way I will use states. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: The simple solution is to not duplicate the state, but instead just do those conditions in the render. If the props dir is up then use that as the class and render the up arrow. No need to store those things as state or instance vars. Please let me know if you don’t understand what I’m suggesting it’s an important concept.

Comment: Yes, I used that logic in `render()` and its working fine. thanks for the suggestion